# What is the name of the hose that comes out of the oil fill?

Tags: oil, hose

What is the name of the hose that comes out of the oil fill in a Dodge Ram 1500 V8 5.7L Hemi truck? Mine is disintegrated and leaking oil. I want to replace it, but I can't find a drawing or part number for this hose anywhere online.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's the **crankcase vent hose**. It provides crankcase ventilation by relieving pressure and scavenging fumes from the crankcase then recirculating them through the air filter. A 5/8" or 3/4" (depending on the ID of the original) heater hose should do in a pinch for a replacement but an OEM product seems readily available.

[image] [image] [image]

The images above are for a 03-04 Dodge Ram 1500 Crankcase Vent Hose Genuine Factory Mopar New OEM.

Comment: Thank you. Do I just pull the old one off and put this one on? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: No more complicated than how you describe. As a 'breather' tube it isn't important to seal the connections with goop or hose clamps so it's a 2 minute operation with no more tools than a glove. Twisting the hose as you pull it off the nipples will ease removal. If it's really stuck and you risk damaging the nipples, split it length-wise with a carpet knife and peel it off the nipples.

Comment: Inside the air cleaner compartment there should be a small piece of loose foam where the vent tube enters from the outside. Its intent is to catch oil 'spit' up through the vent tube. You may want to rinse this in varsol or similar solvent to clean it. It doesn't need replacement unless it is disintegrating.